# Collinear/non-collinear vector algebra problem

Tags: vectors

Let $a,b,c$ be $3$ non zero vectors which are pairwise non collinear. If $a+3b$ is collinear with $c$ and $ b+2c$ is collinear with $a$, then $a+3b+6c$ is how much?

All I can make out with this is $a+3b$ is equal to some $kc$ and $b+2c$ is equal to some $pa$, where $k$ and $p$ are some real scalars.

How do I proceed from here. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have

$$\begin{cases}a+3b=\lambda c \\ b+2c=\mu a\end{cases}\quad\quad\lambda, \mu\in\Bbb R$$

$\implies$

$$\begin{cases}a+3b=\lambda c \\ 3b=3\mu a-6c\end{cases}\quad\quad\lambda, \mu\in\Bbb R$$

$\implies$

$$a+3\mu a-6c = \lambda c \quad\quad\lambda, \mu\in\Bbb R$$

$\implies$

$$(1+3\mu)a= (6+\lambda)c \quad\quad\lambda, \mu\in\Bbb R$$

Since $a$ and $c$ are non-collinear, the only way this can be true is if

$$\begin{cases}1+3\mu=0\\6+\lambda=0\end{cases}$$

Now you should be able to solve.

Comment: is it a general property that if two vectors are colliner, as a and c, then will P,Q be zero in Pa=Qc?

Comment: @LokeshSangewar Non-collinear*. If you draw a diagram, you should see it immediately. Since the vectors point in non-parallel directions, $Pa=Qc$ will never hold unless $P=Q=0$. Another way of thinking about it is that non-collinear vectors are linearly independent. Vectors $\{v_1,v_2,...,v_n\}$ are linearly independent $\iff (\sum^n_{i=1}\lambda_iv_i=0 \iff \lambda_1=\lambda_2=...=\lambda_n=0)$

Comment: Ok thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

We have $a+3b=Kc$, which means $c=\frac1K(a+3b)$

Now, plugging that in to $b+2c=Pa$, we obtain:

$$b+\frac2K(a+3b)=Pa$$

or

$$b+\frac6K b + \frac2K a = Pa$$

Since $a$ and $b$ are non-collinear, we can conclude that the $b$-coefficient on the left is $0$, so $K=-6$.

Can you take it from there?

Answer (score 1):

Since

$$a+3b+6c=kc+6c=c(k+6)$$
$$a+3b+6c=a+3(b+2c)=a+3pa=a(1+3p)$$

we must have

$$c(k+6)=a(1+3p)$$

But since $a$ and $c$ are non-collinear the only solution is

$$\begin{cases}k+6 = 0\\ 1+3p=0\end{cases}$$